# what does the error mean"Server Error in '/' Application."

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace LibraryProgram
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService2
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService2 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public List<string> Getbookname(string bookname)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LibraryDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            List<string> booknames = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getbookname", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@bookname", bookname);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    booknames.Add(rdr["Name"].ToString());
                }
                return booknames;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It shows the error in

```
Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebService1.asmx.cs" Class="LibraryProgram.WebService1" %>
```

But I can't find this line.where can I find this line. please help me.I have already seen about this error.Somebody posted that change codefile instead of codebehind.but I cant find the line in code. thank you

Comment: use Class="LibraryProgram.WebService2" instead of Class="LibraryProgram.WebService1" in webservices.asmx file Line 1:

Comment: did you change your class name from WebService1 to WebService2 ?

Comment: can you please tell me where the line will be found. I can't find this line

Comment: this line in your question Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="WebService1.asmx.cs" Class="LibraryProgram.WebService1" %>

Comment: yes I changed.But it showing the same error. But the line is shown only in error page

Comment: what is the name of your asmx file ?

Comment: This is in the designer .asmx file. Since it's a web service, when you double-click on this it goes directly to the .cs file as there's no real design surface for a web service. Right-click on the .asmx file and select the option to View Designer. You can also hit Shift + F7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have changed the default service name from `Service1` to `Service2`. Please check by right-clicking the `.asmx` file and select "View Markup", it will show you the mark up as:-

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Service.asmx.cs" Class="Service.Service1" %>
```

Change it to:-

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Service.asmx.cs" Class="Service.Service2" %>
```

Please note I have used dummy namespace & service names here, actual names must be different.